# Running try-runtime with try-state option doesn't fail

Tags: try-runtime

When running the following command the try-state fails as it should(I purposefully made the try-state for the Collective pallet incorrect so that it fails):

```
./substrate-try-runtime try-runtime \
    --runtime runtime-try-runtime.wasm \
    -lruntime=debug \
    execute-block \
    live --uri ws://localhost:9944
```

The output (just the error message):

```
2023-04-04 21:32:07.443 ERROR main runtime::executive: failure: "The member count is greater than `MaxMembers`."    
2023-04-04 21:32:07.443 ERROR main runtime: panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: "The member count is greater than `MaxMembers`."', /Users/sergejsakac/substrate-try-state/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs:2362:92    
Error: Input("failed to execute TryRuntime_execute_block: Execution aborted due to trap: wasm trap: wasm `unreachable` instruction executed\nWASM backtrace:\nerror while executing at wasm backtrace:\n    0: 0x60116b - <unknown>!rust_begin_unwind\n    1: 0xd570 - <unknown>!core::panicking::panic_fmt::h78a1ce1c13a708f9\n    2: 0xd904 - <unknown>!core::result::unwrap_failed::he4f8c27dd4e34635\n    3: 0x169e2e - <unknown>!TryRuntime_execute_block\nnote: using the `WASMTIME_BACKTRACE_DETAILS=1` environment variable may show more debugging information")
```

But when running try-state for a specific pallet, in this case the Collective pallet, it doesn't fail:

```
./substrate-try-runtime try-runtime \
    --runtime runtime-try-runtime.wasm \
    -lruntime=debug \
    execute-block \
    --try-state Collective \      
    live --uri ws://localhost:9944
```

The output - no errors even though it should error:

```
2023-04-04 21:34:24.986  INFO main remote-ext: since no at is provided, setting it to latest finalized head, 0x6a5aebcbc8c318095aa9b2c21c276c5532e487c22ccdc7ab431d258d186c81f6    
2023-04-04 21:34:24.986  INFO main remote-ext: since no prefix is filtered, the data for all pallets will be downloaded    
2023-04-04 21:34:24.992  INFO main remote-ext: scraping key-pairs from remote at block height 0x6a5aebcbc8c318095aa9b2c21c276c5532e487c22ccdc7ab431d258d186c81f6    
2023-04-04 21:34:24.993  INFO main remote-ext: Querying a total of 325 keys from prefix , splitting among 8 threads, 41 keys per thread    
2023-04-04 21:34:25.025  INFO main remote-ext: adding data for hashed prefix: , took 0s    
2023-04-04 21:34:25.025  INFO main remote-ext: adding data for hashed key: 3a636f6465    
2023-04-04 21:34:25.047  INFO main remote-ext: adding data for hashed key: 26aa394eea5630e07c48ae0c9558cef7f9cce9c888469bb1a0dceaa129672ef8    
2023-04-04 21:34:25.047  INFO main remote-ext: adding data for hashed key: 26aa394eea5630e07c48ae0c9558cef702a5c1b19ab7a04f536c519aca4983ac    
2023-04-04 21:34:25.048  INFO main remote-ext: initialized state externalities with storage root 0xb155aa408e5275c188dab0d4f701af8c2ed1abd66b0fc21f21e750bf23ea1d3f and state_version V1    
2023-04-04 21:34:25.151  INFO main try-runtime::cli: original spec: RuntimeString::Owned("node")-268, code hash: 6ee5db9e3ab54621fddeb77d9e2c81f278c293c6ef082bb1689744985cf42806    
2023-04-04 21:34:25.232  INFO main try-runtime::cli: new spec: RuntimeString::Owned("node")-268, code hash: 90b9555868002db9d1aac9a46da4323ed10ac1ee21f5f2787b50c939577e620a    
2023-04-04 21:34:25.308  INFO main try-runtime::cli: fetching next block: 0xe6ac87d01558e96981deb788784ef69b5ddf3edccde48d48b29e4b10a05f0fea     
2023-04-04 21:34:26.623  INFO main runtime::executive: try-runtime: executing block #148 / state root check: false / signature check: false / try-state-select: Only(["Collective"])    
2023-04-04 21:34:26.624 DEBUG main runtime::mmr::offchain: offchain db set: pos 290 parent_hash 0x6a5aebcbc8c318095aa9b2c21c276c5532e487c22ccdc7ab431d258d186c81f6 key [12, 109, 109, 114, 34, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 106, 90, 235, 203, 200, 195, 24, 9, 90, 169, 178, 194, 28, 39, 108, 85, 50, 228, 135, 194, 44, 205, 199, 171, 67, 29, 37, 141, 24, 108, 129, 246]    
2023-04-04 21:34:26.624 DEBUG main runtime::mmr::offchain: offchain db set: pos 291 parent_hash 0x6a5aebcbc8c318095aa9b2c21c276c5532e487c22ccdc7ab431d258d186c81f6 key [12, 109, 109, 114, 35, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 106, 90, 235, 203, 200, 195, 24, 9, 90, 169, 178, 194, 28, 39, 108, 85, 50, 228, 135, 194, 44, 205, 199, 171, 67, 29, 37, 141, 24, 108, 129, 246]    
2023-04-04 21:34:26.624 DEBUG main runtime::mmr::offchain: offchain db set: pos 292 parent_hash 0x6a5aebcbc8c318095aa9b2c21c276c5532e487c22ccdc7ab431d258d186c81f6 key [12, 109, 109, 114, 36, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 106, 90, 235, 203, 200, 195, 24, 9, 90, 169, 178, 194, 28, 39, 108, 85, 50, 228, 135, 194, 44, 205, 199, 171, 67, 29, 37, 141, 24, 108, 129, 246]    
2023-04-04 21:34:26.625 DEBUG main runtime::system: [148] 0 extrinsics, length: 11 (normal 0%, op: 0%, mandatory 0%) / normal weight:Weight(ref_time: 0, proof_size: 0) (0%) op weight Weight(ref_time: 0, proof_size: 0) (0%) / mandatory weight Weight(ref_time: 2997764131, proof_size: 142024) (0%)
```

Isn't the latter command supposed to fail also?

Comment: Can you run with `runtime=debug` and paste the output?

Comment: The second should also fail, if everything is correct.

Comment: @kianenigma I have added the output logs.

Comment: This appears to be a bug. I've created an issue (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/13837) and will try to resolve it some time this or next week.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no pallet named `Collective` defined in `construct_runtime!`.

The pallets implementing `pallet_collective` are named `Council`, `TechnicalCommittee` and `AllianceMotion`.

Try using a name from `construct_runtime!`, e.g.

```
./substrate-try-runtime try-runtime \
    --runtime runtime-try-runtime.wasm \
    -lruntime=debug \
    execute-block \
    --try-state Council \      
    live --uri ws://localhost:9944
```